# Changing states when entities intersect

Tags: entity, state, lwjgl, intersection

I am making a maze that the player has to navigate with the mouse, but they lose when the hit a wall. I want to make sure the player has the mouse in the right place to start, so I am trying to switch to the game state once the mouse intersects with a square indicator on screen.

In the tutorial I was learning from, they did this:

```
public static class Point extends AbstractEntity {

    public Point(double x, double y, double width, double height) {
        super(x, y, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
            glVertex2d(x, y);

    }

    @Override
    public void update(int delta) {
        // Blank

    }
}

Point.setLocation(Mouse.getX(), 480 - Mouse.getY() - 1);

if(Maze1.intersects(Point)){
System.out.println("You would have lost");
}
```

I tried to do this:

```
case MAZE:
   if(Maze1.intersects (Point) ){
   state = State.GAMEOVER;
   }
   break;
```

I get the error, "Point cannot be resolved to a variable". Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like when you call Maze1.intersects you are passing the actual Point class rather than an instance of that class. This is why you get the "Point cannot be resolved to a variable" error. You need to create an instance of Point, call setLocation on that instance and then pass that into Maze1.intersects.

For your example to work I would either remove the argument on Maze1.intersects and have it access the Point class directly or change Point to it's no longer static, declare an instance of Point and pass that instance into Maze1.intersect.

Declaring the Point class as static does not mean you can pass the class into method, etc, like a regular variable as it's simply a way of sharing data and behaviour. Also, keep in mind that by declaring Point as static you are saying that there will only ever be one Point.

I would maybe consider dropping the static keyword and creating an instance of Point classed "startingPoint". You can then pass this into Maze1.intersects. Then if you need to determine if the player intersects with other "points" in the maze, then you can create other instances to represent those points.